# Create a desktop shortcut for a terminal comand

Tags: command-line, mount, sudo, shortcuts

I wanted to create a desktop shortcut that will open terminal, enter a command using sudo and give me a prompt to enter the password.
I did see the other thread with a similar question but I guess because my command uses sudo it did not work, in fact I got no response at all.
The command I want to use is "sudo mount xxxx xxxxx"
Hope someone can help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please link to the answer that did not work for you.

Comment: Try to look here.. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=857244
Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Shortcut-Test
Comment=No comment for now
Exec=sudo mount xxxx xxxxx
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Should do the trick/ forgot to set Terminal to true to have the password asked

Comment: `sudo mount...` always try your own answers. Where should we enter the password?

Comment: Forgot to put Terminal=true, you're right

Comment: Thanks Diogo, I created a file called mount.sh with the contents as follows.  "[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Shortcut-Test
Comment=No comment for now
Exec=sudo mount 192.168.0.111:/mnt/b6d67b0a-8dea-4656-a457-0b1c45f83230/Pictures /home/jonh/H8
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utilities;Application; "  in preferences I selected permissions and allow executing file as program however when I double click the resulting file or right click and select the run I get no response.

Comment: You should name it mount.desktop and put it in the desktop folder

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. If I want to mount a 2nd directory can I just repeat the Exec= line?

Comment: you can put this way: Exec=sudo mount xxxx xxxxx; sudo mount yyyy yyyy
If it helped you can upvote :-)

Comment: Excellent thanks, 1 final question. Once created the file changes to the diamond shaped icon of an application and I don't see anyway to edit it afterwards. Is there a simple method for editing the file to add the 2nd mount instructions?

Comment: Ok to change it open a text editor e.g. sublime, gedit, etc. and select the file to be open.

Comment: ok thanks, that didn't work but no problem I just created a 2nd shortcut to the 2nd mount and all is good. Thank you so much for your help and patience. Ticked this but couldn't up vote as it won't let me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use your mouse.
Grab the icon for terminal, slide to desktop then release.
Click on this new desktop icon to bring up your terminal.

Comment: OP obviously is not referring to an existing application. Even if it were, it still needs to be made executable, but again, it isn't.